# What is /service/pcm_client in Oracle BRM?

Tags: oracle

I'm involved in a dispute with a hosting provider over some fees that they claim I accepted. Part of their "proof" is a record from what I believe to be Oracle BRM. It includes the text:

```
PIN_FLD_USERID         POID [0] 0.0.0.1 /service/pcm_client 1 0
```

They claim that "/service/pcm_client is a root user meaning the User Id which has the Primary account access", and this is proof that my primary user account authorized the transaction. (I know this isn't true because of the timestamp on the transaction and because I don't remember doing it.)

So, what does "/service/pcm_client" actually mean in Oracle BRM land?

Comment: first link in google https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16754_01/doc.75/e16719/adm_security.htm#BRMSA310 `When you install BRM, the system creates a single user account, called root and identified by the password password, with general permission to the BRM system. This account includes two services: admin_client and pcm_client.

BRM client applications log in to the admin_client service.

Other BRM utilities and programs, such as optional service integration components, log in to the pcm_client service.`

Comment: so basically this record means that `something` but not main brm client app did it